# FFmpeg GIF dump & video slideshow errors

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, scripting

I'm running Windows 10 and have the latest static 64bit nightly FFmpeg version. Here are my scripts, I've been trying to get them fixed but I can't seem to get either to work.

I have a GIF file named gif.gif that I need the frames dumped out of and named in this order: img000.png img001.png img002.png and so forth.

```
ffmpeg -i "gif.gif" "%img%%03d.png"
```

It's error message is:

> [NULL @ 052857c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'C:\Users\username'
>   C:\Users\username: Invalid argument

This is where I need the individual frames to be encoded into a video file and get it to duplicate the frames necessary to make it a slideshow. It should copy each frame 150 times so that they will last for 5s each at 30fps.
The filename is video maker.bat

```
ffmpeg -i %img%%03d.png -framerate 1/5 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4"
```

It's error message is:

> imgC:\myfilesdirectoryhere\video maker.bat3d.png: Protocol not found

Comment: To keep the ffmpeg format specifier `%03d` from being interpreted by cmd.exe the percent sign has to be escaped by a second one `%%03d`

Comment: @LotPings Okay, is that not what I had?

Comment: No, cmd.exe takes `%img%` as an environment variable `img` if it is empty it renders to nothing. That leaves only one `%`

Comment: @LotPings Wow you're right! They both work now, thanks!

Comment: I needed to also move -framerate 1/5 before -i to work, like this: ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i "img%%03d.png" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "output.mp4"